# SQLite and Python - Fetch value from DB

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table in sqlite DB (alpha.db) named *alphanum* and it has the following columns and values in it.

[image]

I have a function in python to fetch values from this DB:

```
import sqlite3
def viewdata(number):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("alpha.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(("SELECT Alpha,beta,gamma, number FROM alphanum WHERE number=?"),(number,))
    data=cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return data


print(viewdata(2.6))
```

if I use this I am getting the following value:

```
45,54,87,2.6
```

Here, the number column holds the starting value, i.e., from Number 2.6 till 5.9 it belongs to Queue 1, from Number 6 till 8.4, it belongs to Queue 2 and so on.

Now, if I want to get the Alpha, Beta, Gamma values from this table for a number that lies between these Queue what query should I use? i.e., if I input the value of 5.8, I should get the alpha beta and gamma values of Queue 1 since from Number 2.6 till Number 5.9 it belongs to Queue 1.

I am not sure on how to use Declare variables in SQLite, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is number unique?

Comment: Yes, they are cumulative

Comment: Changing you SQL query might help you do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers are cumulative, as per your comment, all you need is to fetch the entries whose `Number` value is lower or equal to the passed number and pick only the highest one, e.g.:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Number FROM alphanum 
               WHERE Number<=? ORDER BY Number DESC LIMIT 1""", (number, ))
```